# While Returning Json Data to spring viewer is giving error

Tags: json, spring

My request handler look like this

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/jsonTable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView populateJsonTable(@ModelAttribute("model") Person model) {
       DataTables<Person> dt = new DataTables<Person>();
       Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       Person person = new Person();
       List<Person> personList = person.findMatches(ctxt.getSession(), 1);
       dt.setEntityData(personList);
       dt.setiTotalDisplayRecords(5);
       result.put("personList", JsonUtil.toJson(dt));
       return new ModelAndView("TeamViewer", result);
    }
```

Jsp page look like this

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <c:set var="baseURL" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
    <link href="${baseURL}/css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="${baseURL}/css/jtable_green.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="${baseURL}/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${baseURL}/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="${baseURL}/js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${baseURL}/js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

When i hit the ("http://localhost:8080/sample/view/jsonTable") url the its show the following error.
```

Error : The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

can any body tell what wrong with this code.

I want to make one data Grid with Json. So my Idea is take data from data base as Java model and then convert it in to json form. and then suply it to browser. For this i m pasting some more of TeamViewer. jsp. Or if you can some other link where java data is converted in json form and then render it into jsp. then plz share it.

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" >
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <c:set var="baseURL" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
        <link href="${baseURL}/css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="${baseURL}/css/jtable_green.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="${baseURL}/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${baseURL}/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="${baseURL}/js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="${baseURL}/js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

        var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
            console.log( "success" );
            })
            .done(function() {
            console.log( "second success" );
            })
            .fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
            })
            .always(function() {
            console.log( "complete" );
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {      

                //setup hellothe jtable that will display the results
                $('#ExpenseTableContainer').jtable({
                    title: 'Table of Expenses',
                    selecting: true, //Enable selecting 
                    paging: true, //Enable paging
                    pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
                    sorting: true, //Enable sorting
                    actions: {
                        listAction: '${baseURL}/view/jsontable',
//                         createAction: '${baseURL}/datatable/addExpense',
//                         updateAction: '${baseURL}/datatable/updateExpense',
//                         deleteAction: '${baseURL}/datatable/deleteExpense'
                    },
                    fields: {
                        Id: {
                            key: true,
                            list: true,
                            create: false,
                            edit: false
                        },

                        Name: {
                            key: true,
                            list: true,
                            create: false,
                            edit: false
                        },

                        FirstName: {
                            title : 'First Name',
                            width : 30%''
                        },
                        Date: {
                            title: 'Date',
                            width: '30%'
                        },
                        Amount: {
                            title: 'Amount',
                            width: '15%'
                        },
                        CategoryId: {
                            title: 'Category',
                            options: '${baseURL}/datatable/categories'
                        },
                        SubcategoryId: {
                            title: 'Sub Category',
                            dependsOn: 'CategoryId',
                            options: function (data) {
                                if (data.source == 'list') {
                                    //Return url of all countries for optimization.
                                    //This method is called for each row on the table and jTable caches options based on this url.
                                    return '${baseURL}datatable/subcategories?categoryId=0';
                                }
                                return '${baseURL}/datatable/subcategories?categoryId=' + data.dependedValues.CategoryId;
                            },
                            list: false
                        },        
                        Description: {
                            title: 'Description',
                            width: '25%'
                        }
                    },
                    rowInserted: function (event, data) {
                        //if (data.record.Name.indexOf('Andrew') >= 0) {
                            $('#ExpenseTableContainer').jtable('selectRows', data.row);
                            console.log("records inserted");
                            //$('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');
                        //}
                    },
                    //Register to selectionChanged event to hanlde events                                     
                    recordAdded: function(event, data){
                        //after record insertion, reload the records
                        $('#ExpenseTableContainer').jtable('load');
                    },
                    recordUpdated: function(event, data){
                        //after record updation, reload the records
                        $('#ExpenseTableContainer').jtable('load');
                    }
                });
                $('#ExpenseTableContainer').jtable('load');              

            });    
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but @ResponseBody seems to be the problem. This annotation tells Spring to serialize the object returned by the method and send it to the client. If you are returning a ModelAndView you probably want the rendered view named TeamViewer to be sent to the client. 
In short, remove the @ResponseBody.